# Tip still showing Database access elements in loop

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, database

I have a loop in a flow where I have multiple Get elements which are clearly placed after the "After Last" path when the loop is complete. But the Flow 'Tips' is still telling me almost every database element from that point forward is still in the loop. Is there a definitive way to ensure the flow recognizes the end of the loop before moving on to the database elements?

I do have a decision within the loop where one of the paths leaves the loop and connects to a path outside of the loop.

[image: Loop within flow]

Comment: In the RuleId Assigned decision, aren't both the Yes and No path doing the same thing?

Comment: @NickCook no, the Yes path leaves the loop and connects to the first Get Records element outside of the loop. The no path returns to the loop start.

Comment: but the No path finishes the execution for that element, meaning that element's next step is the same as the Yes path.  With the Yes path, is the intention to stop the loop? ie. break out of the loop and don't process any more elements in the collection?

Comment: The No path continues the loop. The Yes path connects with a path outside of the loop. Note the highlighted "GetRuleforProgram" under the Yes path. This jumps outside of the loop to the next Get Records element.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  With the Yes path, is the intention to stop the loop? ie. break out of the loop and don't process any more elements in the collection?

Comment: Nick, as stated above, the Yes path breaks out of the loop, so, yes, the intention is to stop the loop. I am just going to use the counter. Thanks for trying.